# Getting redirect_uri_mismatch error with multiple uris

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0

I am trying to consume Google Oauth v2. I go into my api console and setup the following 2 redirect uris...

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/authenticate
http://localhost:3000/auth/google/getToken
```

When I run the following...

```
curl -d "code=<removed>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2fgetToken&client_id=<removed>&client_secret=<removed>&grant_type=authorization_code" -X POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

everything works great, however,

```
curl -d "code=<removed>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fauthenticate&client_id=<removed>&client_secret=<removed>&grant_type=authorization_code" -X POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

fails saying...

```
"error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
```

I did just change this, is there a propagation time frame? How do I get both uris to work?

Comment: In the 2nd case, which uri did you use in the initial request?

Comment: Does that matter, I was wondering, do they have to be the same? This seems rather illogical because I would love to have a different callback for each.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described [here](http://hueniverse.com/2011/06/oauth-2-0-redirection-uri-validation/) the second time you send redirect_uri you send it for validation(they need to match) and this is not an arbitrary value. You need to pass the same value for redirect_uri when requesting for access token to the value of redirect_uri in which you asked user to be redirected after authorization. Otherwise google(or any other provider will generate an error message).

Comment: This still doesn't make sense, this means I have to have some logic to tell whether it is the call back with the code or the call back with the access token, etc. I don't see why this is a big deal if the domains are the same. I agree that you answer is probably correct (although I need to test it), however, this seems like it causes unnecessary logic (IE determine what type of response I am getting) on the client side.

Comment: Also what is weird, it doesn't "comeback" to the redirect URL. this doesn't seem to add anything but headache to me. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you're using **Google+ javascript button**, you have to put `postmessage` instead of actual URI. It takes me almost whole day to figure out this, because Google docs doesn't clearly stand it for some reason.

Comment: amazing! thanks, can't understand why this is poorly documented!

Answer (score 1):

An app can have multiple redirect_uri values. However, the same redirect_uri that is used in the initial authorization request (where the user is redirected) needs to be used in the token request. Changing uris on a single authorization will fail with that error.